# Hibernate throws exception but SQL it generates works fine when i run it on my DBMS

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have just recently made some changes to my DB structure, and when i was going to test the application, it throws an exception on a simple repository.findByEmail(email) that i use for my login. It throws an exception saying that one of the new tables i created has a column that does not exist (even though it does). I turned on SQL logging in hibernate, and copied the query it showed was not working and ran it on DBeaver, the IDE i use for running SQL commands, and it works just fine.

SQL code generated by Hibernate:

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        profile0_.id as id1_8_0_,
        profile0_.name as name2_8_0_,
        roles1_.id_profile as id_profi1_9_1_,
        role2_.id as id_role2_9_1_,
        role2_.id as id1_10_2_,
        role2_.name as name2_10_2_ 
    from
        profile profile0_ 
    left outer join
        profile_roles roles1_ 
            on profile0_.id=roles1_.id_profile 
    left outer join
        role role2_ 
            on roles1_.id_role=role2_.id 
    where
        profile0_.id=?
```

Error messages in debug (I only copied the main ones, but i can send the whole debug if it will help:

```sql
2019-10-07 10:41:41.035  WARN 2492 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, 
SQLState: 42703
2019-10-07 10:41:41.035 ERROR 2492 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: column profile0_.id does not exist
  Posição: 245
2019-10-07 10:41:41.052  INFO 2492 --- [nio-8443-exec-6] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column profile0_.id does not exist
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized what happened. I had another table with that name on another schema that didnt have that column. All i had to do was add the schema property on the @Table annotation